# Visual Studio 2017 Python Environment not working

Tags: python, visual-studio, environment-variables, intellisense

I have a problem with my Visual Studio 2017 Community. I installed Visual with Python, but Intellisense doesn't detect Python modules. 
[Screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGLG3.png)

[Screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ffwA.png)

[Screen3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8lVD.png)

[Screen4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4HGR.png)

I repaired Visual Studio - it doesn't solve problem.
I reinstall python 3.64 - it also doesn't solve problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the SO tour and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please don't post pictures of code and error messages, post the text directly here on SO. And I suggest including more details.

Answer (score 0):

Please open Tools/Options, find Python and click on its Experimental tab. The first checkbox should be checked (you will need to restart Visual Studio after changing it) - this should resolve many issues you are seeing.

I'd also suggest working through [the tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/python/tutorial-working-with-python-in-visual-studio-step-00-installation) for working with Python in Visual Studio. It will help ensure that you have things correctly configured.

Answer (score 0):

best to use the python IDE if you still cannot get it to work or just use pycharm

or just go on visual studios and download the tool that lets you run python